# Why is Deployment Descriptor node in Project Explorer missing with Dynamic Web Module 5.0?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, eclipse-jee

I read that the Eclipse Facet : **Dynamic Web Module 5.0** has changed from **4.0** only by a change of the namespace (from: [Jakarta Servlet Specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.pdf)).

I tried indeed to change my version from 4 to 5 and from 5 to 4 and everything works fine.

In version 5.0 however, Eclipse is not showing the Deployment Descriptor node in the "Project Explorer" view.
This node is quite cool because it lists any filter or listener defined in the web.xml file.

[image]

Anyone know **how to make this node come back with Dynamic Web Module 5.0, or at least why is it absent ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OP didn't check back and report it as a bug, I opened bug [580016](https://bugs.eclipse.org/580016).